# Select all but first class element not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select all, but the first class element. I'm doing `.title:not(:first-child)`, but it's not working.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it? Here's the code:

#### JSFiddle

```css
.title:not(:first-child) {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <h4 class="title">First Tittle</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <h4 class="title">Second Tittle</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your title is always the first child.
Try the following:

```
.inner-wrapper:not(:first-child) .title{
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Or

```
.inner-wrapper:nth-child(n+1) .title{
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Why is `.title` always the first child? Does it not go by class's?

Comment: Its relative to its parent. So the `.title` in your markup is the first child of `.inner-wrapper`.